# Pound Sign Not Showing in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have read through this forum but not explains "how to" in a wordpress situation. Im not a coder so please take your time with me but I do know where to put codes if you tell me to.

This issue is that the "£" is not showing up but if I go to, in firefox, char enco > ISO 8859-1 all works well. Is it possible, in wordpress theme, to force the browser to use iso 8859-1?

In plain html if I use `&pound` that works but wordpress is php that Im not used to at the moment. Any help or advise would be appreciated.

You can view the page here: http://www.imayne.co.uk/products-page/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your document is UTF-8, so you should be able to use

```
&pound;
```

You did mention this in your question - it shouldn't make a difference whether the HTML is created by PHP or not.

Post some source from where you are adding this if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Sohnee. The pound sign shows up on other pages but not on the page with a plugin's page im using. Im using a ecommerce plugin and it does not show the £ sign.

Answer (score 0):

try `&#163;`
That should do the trick.

Comment: To everyone: I have a currency_list.php and it has entity number. The php looks like this:

<code>

INSERT INTO `".WPSC_TABLE_CURRENCY_LIST."` VALUES (223, 'U.K.', 'UK', 'Pound Sterling', 'GBP', '&#163;', 'GBP', '0', '17.5','europe','1');
</code>

Im not sure how to make this looks neat like the most of you do. :)

Comment: Well that is probably the cleanest it will go, INSERT INTO ".WPSC_TABLE_CURRENCY_LIST."<br />
VALUES (223, 'U.K.', 'UK', 'Pound Sterling', 'GBP', '&#163;', 'GBP', '0', '17.5','europe','1');

Comment: Ok but what's the solution? It has to do with this ISO thing.

Comment: '\&\#163\;'
That should be allowable.